# Finding JVM Port Library memory usage details

Tags: java, memory, jvm

This is from a core dump of a running IBM JVM (1.7).
How can I find for what is the "Port Library" memory used for (185,624,064B)? 
What does it means "unused"?

```
    0SECTION       NATIVEMEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
0MEMUSER
1MEMUSER       JRE: 593,910,528 bytes / 7280 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--VM: 544,510,528 bytes / 5987 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Classes: 57,037,616 bytes / 1746 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Shared Class Cache: 16,777,312 bytes / 2 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 40,260,304 bytes / 1744 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Memory Manager (GC): 276,343,080 bytes / 794 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Heap: 268,439,552 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 7,903,528 bytes / 793 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Threads: 22,618,136 bytes / 409 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Stack: 1,460,272 bytes / 66 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Native Stack: 20,054,016 bytes / 68 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 1,103,848 bytes / 275 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Trace: 721,064 bytes / 418 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JVMTI: 17,784 bytes / 13 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JNI: 701,192 bytes / 1966 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Port Library: 185,624,064 bytes / 68 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Unused <32bit allocation regions: 185,614,504 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 9,560 bytes / 67 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 1,447,592 bytes / 573 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--JIT: 48,401,712 bytes / 1182 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Code Cache: 18,874,368 bytes / 9 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Data Cache: 12,583,296 bytes / 6 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 16,944,048 bytes / 1167 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--Class Libraries: 998,288 bytes / 111 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Harmony Class Libraries: 2,000 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--VM Class Libraries: 996,288 bytes / 110 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--sun.misc.Unsafe: 875,440 bytes / 33 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Direct Byte Buffers: 463,392 bytes / 28 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Other: 412,048 bytes / 5 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 120,848 bytes / 77 allocations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This memory is reserved for use for some native structures (some class- and thread- related data) that need to be in the bottom 4GB of memory when -Xcompressedrefs is used.

The reservation keeps space available in the bottom 4GB of the address space so that it isn't doesn't fill up with other allocations that don't need to reside there.

The size of the reservation can be configured with the `-Xmcrs` option in recent versions. See: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.aix.70.doc/diag/appendixes/cmdline/xmcrs.html

My understanding is that the space is marked unused in the diagnostics as it is not backed by RAM until sub-allocated to a particular purpose, then it will be attributed to another section. So the free space will shrink with time unless more is required, then a new (smaller) chunk will be reserved and added to the unused list.